# Помощь MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я не могу сообразить как правильно нужно написать триггер
чтобы при бронировании определенного номера, шло вычитание из таблицы nf
с тем же номером (id), что был указан при бронировании.

Например бронируется 202 номер на одного человека, после его бронирования значение
в колонке free изменялось на 1 (одно свободное место)
Например еще раз забронировали, изменилось на 0.

И точно также чтобы с остальными номерами.

Comment: Гм... зачем? Количество мест в номере известно, количество актуальных броней - считается по таблице брони, разность даёт количество свободных мест.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в таблице nf шло вычитание в таком АЙДИ (комнаты) в колонке free, который будет равен той комнате, что занесли в таблицу cl в колонку r

Answer (score 0):

SET @id:= LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE 'имяВашейБазы'.c1 SET free=`free`-1 WHERE c1.id=@id;

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Направление я понял, но с помощью других сил, изменил Ваш кусочек кода и добился своей цели

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]